# restore consumable inapp purchases using webservice

Tags: ios, sdk, in-app-purchase, backend, restore

we are using a backend service for the products in the app and a mapping scheme of in-app consumables for the dynamic content (added in the backend and synced to the app) so that a new content added to the backend can be matched with a fixed price of a consumable in app purchase, this way we dont have add a new object with itunes connect when a new item in the backend is added. but how can the restoration of a product be done (since its required by apple)? is it possible to send the receipt of a transaction to the backend and use it for restoring? anyone here who has experience with a similiar solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple does not require you to have restoration for consumable in-app purchases. In fact the StoreKit API and App Receipt does not contain any record of consumable purchases after the transaction has been finished.

See [this doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2413/_index.html) and search for 'Calling the payment queue’s restoreCompletedTransactions method does not restore any products in my application' for more info.

Comment: well thats what we've tried already - we submitted the app without a restoration feature and it got rejected.

Comment: If you are truly selling consumables (coins, etc) I would push back on the app review rejection seeking more answers. Can you give a concrete example of the type of item you are offering for sale?

Comment: the items selling in the app are videos. the consumables however are just placeholders for the videos with the same pricetag - otherwise we would have to add a new video item to itunes connect, for ever new video available - which means adding them to the webstore and also to the itunes connect - but there must be an easier way than doing the work twice for ever item? coins might seem an option, but what happens to coins that are bought when the user switches to a new phone? are the coins lost he bought on the old phone?

Comment: What you are describing does not fit well into the consumable category (unless it's a one time watch video?). The two paths you describe are the likely alternatives. In the case of coins + a new phone, the user would indeed lose those consumables, which is true of all consumables. Do you have user accounts? You could keep track of how many coins a user has on the backend which would protect you against the new phone scenario. Anonymous users would just get a less than optimal experience.